# z-index not working for modal window of Ext Js 4

Tags: extjs, modal-dialog

I have to open one modal window over second modal window. after display second window both are fighting for to be in front.
I already tried bringToFront() method but it did not work.
anybody have solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **defer** opening of the new modal. This is a common problem in ExtJS with most of their auto DOM manipulations on to their components. For example if you try setting values to a form object immediately after it's creation, you may notice that it doesn't work (at least for me it doesn't). After trying every possible method that ExtJS has in it's library, it took me a few frustrating hours to come up with this solution (and by far the only solution that had worked for me). I still have no idea why such a thing happens and why deferring does the trick (any enlightenment over this would be highly appreciated).

Having said that, the way to do it is as simple as wrapping you code in an anonymous function and calling it with a timeout (some 10ms should do the trick). You may even use `Ext.Function.defer` that provides some additional options like changing the function scope, passing additional arguments to the function etc. Feel free to try this approach on any of your code that you think should have ideally worked but is not working (like setting component values, show, hide, etc).

```
setTimeout(function(){
  // your code to render the modal or other ExtJS components
  ...
}, 10);

// or do it the ExtJS way

Ext.Function.defer(function(){
  ...
}, 1); // giving 1ms works in most cases
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Ext.WindowManager.bringToFront(window);
```

Should work, [here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amitaviv99/ahwsT/11/).

Answer (score 0):

Give them different id/class and give them diferent zindex on the CSS. Should work.